# Error with neuralnet in R

Tags: r

I am trying to implement a basic neural network

```
library (neuralnet)
set.seed(2016)
attribute <- as.data.frame(sample(seq(-2,2, length =50),50, replace = FALSE ),ncol =1)
response <- attribute ^2

data <- cbind ( attribute , response)
colnames(data) <- c(" attribute "," response")
head (data ,10)

fit <- neuralnet(response~attribute, data = data,hidden =c(3 ,3),threshold =0.01)
testdata <- as.matrix(sample(seq(-2,2,length =10), 10, replace = FALSE ), ncol =1)
pred <- compute(fit , testdata)

result <- cbind (testdata , pred $net.result, testdata ^2)
colnames (result) <- c(" Attribute ","Prediction ", " Actual ")
round (result ,4)
```

I am getting the following error for neuralnet command

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula.reverse, data) :invalid type (list) for variable 'attribute'
```

Can someone explain how this can be resolved ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Space in the name of the "attribute" while assigning name
colnames(data) <- c(" attribute "," response")

Remove it extra space & it works fine
colnames(data) <- c("attribute","response")